# XSLT - Grouping dynamic nodes within apply-template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml like this,

```
<doc>
    <aa type="xx">aaaa</aa>
    <aa type="xx">bbbb</aa>
    <aa type="yy">ccccc</aa>
    <aa type="zz">dddd</aa>
    <aa type="yy">eeee</aa>
    <aa type="xx">ffff</aa>
    <aa type="yy">gggg</aa>
</doc>
```

in my scenario the type attribute is a variable , i need to group the above xml in orderly by checking type attribute, type attr value appear in top should take priority, so the output should be

```
<doc>
    <aa type="xx">aaaa</aa>
    <aa type="xx">bbbb</aa>
    <aa type="xx">ffff</aa>
    <aa type="yy">ccccc</aa>
    <aa type="yy">eeee</aa>
    <aa type="yy">gggg</aa>
    <aa type="zz">dddd</aa>       
</doc>
```

since the type attribute value is a variable (I dont know the exact type value), I wrote a template like follows,

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
    <doc>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="aa[@type='{@type}']"/>
    </doc>
</xsl:template>
```

using `group-by` it would be easier to implememt a method to do the task, but can I do this only using `apply-template`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to apply templates on all `<aa>` nodes in an ordered fashion. You can do this with for-each, which allows sorting:

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
    <doc>
        <xsl:for-each select="aa">
            <xsl:sort select="@type"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </doc>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: `xsl:sort` works on `xsl:apply-templates` too, so you can simplify it to `<xsl:apply-templates select="aa"><xsl:sort select="@type"/></xsl:apply-templates>`